# How to adjust vertical & horizontal perspective for photos on Mac OS (like on iOS)?

Tags: macos, ios, photos.app, image-editing

In Apple's Photo app on my iPhone, I can **straighten** and *adjust vertical & horizontal perspective* for photos as shown in my image below and also described on [this page](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/edit-photos-and-videos-iphb08064d57/ios).

[image]

But in Apple's Photo app on my Mac I can only see how to **straighten** photos.  I see no way to *adjust vertical & horizontal perspective* (tilt) for photos.

My question is: how can I *adjust vertical & horizontal perspective* on photos using my Mac? I want to do this using apps that come with  Mac OS, like the Photo app, Preview, etc...

Comment: I agree with the loss of these essential tools on MacOS. Digging around, it seems this is not possible with just the applications that ship with MacOS. Where Photos on MacOS is missing vertical and horizontal plane adjustments, it has a red eye tool, an object remover, curves and level editors, etc. iOS Photos has none of those. There is a definite disparity between the Photos apps on the two operating systems. The user guide for Big Sur shows what you get and do not get: https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/editing-basics-pht304c2ace6/mac.

Comment: You don't need to add "Solved" to the title. Questions with an accepted answer are marked green in the question list automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: The desired feature is now present on a Mac using Photos 8.0 (511.0.180) (at least on my M1 MacAir running Mac OS 13.0.1). As shown in the screenshot below, the controls appear when using the "crop" tool while editing a photo. Since this post reached the status of a "Notable Question" (over 2500 views) perhaps someone at Apple paid attention.

[image]

=====
Original answer:
After researching more I found an [Apple site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252319871) that claims the original question (“the controls to correct the horizontal or vertical perspective distortion") is “simply not yet possible on a Mac”

In searching for other options, I learned that this is called a “keystone correction” or (perhaps less precisely) “distortion correction”

According to [this site](https://www.petervis.com/gallery/soft/Digital%20Camera%20Corrections/Correcting%20Perspective.html) “Currently Gimp is the only freeware graphics package I know that has the capability to correct distortions” and they provide instructions for how to do it.

Given the Apple’s trend to converge Mac OS and iOS features, it might become available. But until that time, it seems the shortest path to getting the desired result is to do the adjustments in the iOS Photos app and then transfer the photo to the mac.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility to apply a keystone correction in macOS Photos (at the moment), is to download & install an extension (go the the macOS App store and search for "photos extension"). Select the photo, click "Edit" then click the button with the 3 dots in it to start the extension.